# jQuery and JavaScript not working in MultiView

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, datalist

I'm using a datalist in a multiview that's in a update panel to display various amount of data. OnItemDataBound in the DataList, depending on the item, it adds a jQuery code encased in a div. Does anyone know how to fix this code so it works?. Here's some sample code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
     <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:MultiView runat="server">
              <asp:View runat="server">
                  <asp:DataList ID="tmpDataTable" runat="server" 
                       DataSourceID="tmpDataSource" 
                       OnItemDataBound="tmpDataBound">
                          <ItemTemplate>
                             <a id="tstATag" runat="server" onclick="testingAlert();">
                                 <%# Eval("Text_Col") %><a>
                          </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:DataList>
              <asp:SqlDataSource OnSelecting="PermSet" ID="tmpDataSource" 
                      runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Con %>"
                      SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM SampleTable">
              </asp:SqlDataSource>
              <div runat="server id="tmpDiv"></div>
          </asp:View>
      </asp:MultiView>
   </ContentTemplate>
```

Here's the backend code:

```
protected void tmpDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
                e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl tstATag = e.Item.FindControl("tstATag") as HtmlGenericControl;
        tmpDiv.InnerHtml += @"   <script type='text/javascript'>
                                                    function testingAlert() {
                                                        alert(tstATag.innerHtml);
                                                    }

                                                </script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: @PrasanthVJ my question is, how do I fix it so this works?

Comment: There is a extra repeater code in your design page change that to datalist

Comment: @PrasanthVJ sorry about that. I copied the wrong code. I just tested it as is and the JavaScript still doesn't work.

Comment: You need the div with javascript in the bottom of the list right?

Comment: So if there are five items in your datalist then you want to add five scripts in div and all script will have same function?

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up finding out is when you are viewing a different view in a multiview you have do a full page postback in order for the scripts to register correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting div innerhtml from  onitemdatabound do it from page load

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tmpDiv.InnerHtml += @"   <script type='text/javascript'>
                                                        function testingAlert() {
                                                            alert('Testing');
                                                        }

                                                    </script>";
        }
```

Comment: The reason I used OnItemDataBound is because in the actual code it uses the data from the database alerts the user with that. Check the edited code.

Comment: If you add this script in itemdatabound the same code will be added to the page on each row bind.And you have to call the javascript function to trigger the alert

Comment: I know that. The code does do all of that. Did you read the edited version?

Comment: Still you are not telling what is your issue?I tried the same code here it is binding the data from database correctly with a bunch of javascript function. I don't know what to do with this function !!!

Comment: Alright. I just tested the code again and it seems when I do a entire page postback the code get's rendered and it works correctly. The problem is the button isn't calling the function because it doesn't believe it exists.

Comment: @StørmShadøws - Which button is not calling the function? Your link inside the databound control or you are talking about any other button?